# How to get all entries of an object if it has one specific value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, orm

I have a Car Model something like below:

```
id | car_name | test_type 
1  | carA     |   P   
2  | carB     |   Q 
3  | carC     |   Q 
4  | carA     |   Q
```

I want to query it in such a way if carA has 'P' as its test_type then result must also contains all the entries for carA.

Expected result for carA:

```
id | car_name | test_type 
1  | carA     |   P  
4  | carA     |   Q
```

Is there a way to do this in Django?

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL query or some django code?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That will also help.

Comment: My apologies for not being direct, I have edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a raw Postgres query which should work:

```sql
SELECT c1.*
FROM cars c1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM cars c2
    WHERE c2.car_name = c1.car_name AND
          c2.test_type = 'P'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will return expected result:

```
select car.* from car left join (select * from car where test_type='P' group by car_name)sub on sub.car_name=car.car_name where sub.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Fire Query in Following way :

SELECT *id,car_name,test_type* from cars where *car_name* = (SELECT *car_name* from cars where *test_type* = 'P');

You will get Result in following Way :

id | car_name | test_type

1 | carA | P

4 | carA | Q

Comment: This will fail if there is more than one row with `test_type = 'P'` for a car.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   car
WHERE  car_name IN (SELECT car_name
                    FROM   car
                    WHERE  test_type = 'P');
```

Comment: I get this, how can we do this in Django's ORM?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for using Django ORM, you can do two queries and get the correct queryset:

```
car = set(Car.objects.filter(test_type='P').values_list('car_name', flat=True)) 
qs_car_with_p = Car.objects.filter(car_name__in=car)
```

Comment: @sachin-m-s code improved.